# running a codeigniter application on localhost/xampp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What versions of PHP and MYSQL should I use, if I want to run a codeigniter application of version 2.2.0 on my XAMPP local host?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter 2.2.0 needs below Server Requirements

1. PHP version 5.1.6 or newer.
2. A Database is required for most web application programming. Current supported databases are MySQL (4.1+), MySQLi, MS SQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQLite, and ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP](http://php.net) version 5.6 or newer is recommended.

It should work on 5.3.7 as well, but we strongly advise you NOT to run such old versions of PHP, because of potential security and performance issues, as well as missing features.

A database is required for most web application programming. Currently supported databases are:

1. MySQL (5.1+) via the mysql (deprecated), mysqli and pdo drivers
2. Oracle via the oci8 and pdo drivers
3. PostgreSQL via the postgre and pdo drivers
4. MS SQL via the mssql, sqlsrv (version 2005 and above only) and pdo drivers
5. SQLite via the sqlite (version 2), sqlite3 (version 3) and pdo drivers
6. CUBRID via the cubrid and pdo drivers
7. Interbase/Firebird via the ibase and pdo drivers
8. ODBC via the odbc and pdo drivers (you should know that ODBC is actually an abstraction layer)

Link [Server Requirements](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Code Igniter 2.2.0

Code Igniter 2.2.0 can be upgraded to (or installed) using any of Installatron's products. Use Installatron's optional Automatic Update feature to automatically apply Code Igniter updates as new versions are released, or use Installatron's Clone feature to duplicate an existing Code Igniter install to test the 2.2.0 upgrade prior to applying it live. Get started managing your Code Igniter installations with Installatron

What's New in Code Igniter 2.2.0

This is a security release for the 2.x branch. The Encryption Class now requires the Mcrypt extension, so please ensure your environment is ready for the update.

General Changes
Security: The xor_encode() method in the Encrypt Class has been removed. The Encrypt Class now requires the Mcrypt extension to be installed.
Security: The Session Library now uses HMAC authentication instead of a simple MD5 checksum.

Bug Fixes
Fixed an edge case (#2583) in the Email Library where Suhosin blocked messages sent via mail() due to trailing newspaces in headers.
Fixed a bug (#696) - make oci_execute() calls inside num_rows() non-committing, since they are only there to reset which row is next in line for oci_fetch calls and thus don't need to be committed.
Fixed a bug (#2689) - Database Forge Class methods create_table(), drop_table() and rename_table() produced broken SQL for tge 'sqlsrv' driver.
Fixed a bug (#2427) - PDO Database driver didn't properly check for query failures.
Fixed a bug in the Session Library where authentication was not performed for encrypted cookies.